# Remove .js file from specific pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application designed with a layout page and few child pages. i have applied all .js files in my layout.chtml.

i want to remove links to some .js files in some child pages.

for example i have below in my layout.chtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/acebs/assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js")"></script>
```

my child page is as follows.

```
@model FeedBackDashBord.Models.ChatLIST
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat Settings";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/layout.cshtml";
}
```

how can i remove the link to jquery.mobile.custom.min.js from my child page?

Comment: have another layout page which does not include the scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an optional section on your layout page. On the specific pages where you don't wish to include the script you would need to provide a value for this section - even if it's just an empty block.

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("OptionalContent")) { 
    @RenderSection("OptionalContent")
}
else { 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/acebs/assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js")"></script>
}
```

More details can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx